# ruby mongo gem where array length greater than

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I have a document which has an array in it, I want to fetch all those documents where array length is > 365.

My document:

```
{
    "_id" : "100064",
        "rec" : [
        {
            "234.59"
        },
        {
            "234.29"
        }]
}
```

Basically how to execute following mongo command in ruby mongo gem:

```
count = db.yyy.find({ $where: "this.rec.length > 365"}).count()
```

-> Results: 3000

I have tried following but haven't got the same result:

```
count = yyy_collection.find("rec.length" => {"$gt" => 365}).count
```

-> Results: 0

```
count = yyy_collection.find({ "rec" => { "$size" => {"$gt" => 365} } }).count
```

-> Results: 0

Comment: Your document appears to have an array with only two elements, so those queries would be correct.  I assume the *actual* array has > 365 elements?

Comment: Yes maerics, The document can have at least 365 elements, but few of them have more and i wanted to identify them. I had put only two elements just for illustration for document structure.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer:

```
count = yyy_collection.find({ "$where" => "this.rec.length > 365" }).count()
```

returns 3000 has the count which was expected.